# What kind of domestic use machine is needed for preparing Brown Rice from Paddy?

Tags: equipment, rice

The brown rice is extremely expensive here so I was wondering if it is possible to get some machine for converting Paddy into Brown rice at home?

What prerequisites need to be fulfilled for the achieving the same? Is it practical even?

Comment: Given what [Wikipedia has to say about milling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rice#Harvesting.2C_drying_and_milling) I can't imagine there's an economical way to do this with any reasonable efficiency without a really expensive machine.

Comment: @Jefromi I think I can assume here the I will purchase the __dried__ paddy. Will it be feasible then?

Comment: I was talking about the part about milling, not the part about drying.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are 3 main types of rice huller in use:

The oldest, [Mortar and pestle](http://www.allposters.com/-sp/Woman-Dressed-for-Carnival-Uses-Mortar-and-Pestle-for-Hulling-Rice-Posters_i6101289_.htm?AID=96280778&ProductTarget=53106044383), takes strength, time and patience.

[Centrifugal hullers](http://www.fao.org/wairdocs/ilri/x5483b/x5483b0j.htm) have been around since the late 1800's, but high speed (5Krpm+) centrifuges are not consumer devices. They can be quite dangerous if not used correctly.

[Rubber roller based hullers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rice_huller) are probably the most common type today. You don't see many consumer friendly units around, but rubber based attachments for Corona mills are [sometimes available.](http://www.southernexposure.com/grain-and-rice-dehuller-attachment-for-the-corona-mill-ezp-28.html)

Once you get your rice dehulled, you'll need to separate the chaff. There are lots of ways to do that, [starting at a low tech level.](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=92OcCcj7jCE)

Comment: Would be interesting to compare the calories needed for processing rice with a mortar and pestle to the calories in the rice.

Answer (score 0):

$160 list of parts here, looks like a solid little manual machine http://www.brillengineering.com/
If you can spend more, maybe try a solar powered mill from http://www.psspng.com